# How to Join Tables on Datetime within a margin of seconds

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 10 tables: Table1, Table2, ..., Table10

Each one with the columns:

- id
- text
- datetime

My task is to join the Table1.datetime  with the rest of the 9 tables.datetime (+-3seconds on the 9 tables) and return the text columns of all tables. I am using postgresql.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if only 9 out of 10 tables have a common timestamp? (Do you want data from that timestamp or not?)

Comment: Great question ,thank you! Yes i want any matched data,even if its 2/10..

Comment: If every table from table2 to table10 has 5 rows which are within that interval of table1, do you want to return 1,953,125 rows (that is, 5^9)?

Comment: No i want to return the the row that is matched with the first table,eg table1.datetime <= table2.datetime etc etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me if the timestamp in `table1` should be within +/- 3 seconds of the other tables or the other way round.

You can join on more complex conditions than just `=`:

```
select t1.text, t2.text, ...
from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 
    on t1.datetime >= t2.datetime - interval '3 seconds'
   and t1.datetime <= t2.datetime + interval '3 seconds'
  join table3 t3
    on t1.datetime >= t3.datetime - interval '3 seconds'
   and t1.datetime <= t3.datetime + interval '3 seconds'
  ... repeat for all tables ...
```

If you are not sure if all tables have a match, you might want a `left join` rather than an inner join.

The above assumes that the `datetime` columns are correctly defined with the data type `timestamp` or `timestamptz`

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, the datetimes column is defined as : **2018-11-03 14:23:24** I used your example but unfortunatelly returned me empty array.I tried also with casting each datetime(datetime::timestamp) but also empty array.I edited the post and i am looking for +-3 of the 9 tables.

Comment: I'd like to add that such a join on big tables will never be efficient.

Comment: Thanks Laurenx,what method would be efficient?